# Sizing RAM for a Postgres Database server

Tags: postgresql

How would you size RAM for a Postgres database server? 
Some folks suggest that it should be equal to the size of indexes on disk?
Other suggestions are based on workload size?
Is there a template that can be used?

Comment: https://github.com/jfcoz/postgresqltuner

Comment: Just installed it, looks good. Coincidentally, I read about it on HackerNews yesterday.Thanks!!